# NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\username\\MYD06_L2.A2008001.0000.006.2013341193524.hdf'

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pyhdf

I am using `Windows 10` and running the code in `Jupyter Notebook` (in `Chrome`).

This is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import itertools
    MOD03_path = r"C:\Users\saviosebastian\MYD03.A2008001.0000.006.2012066122450.hdf"
    MOD06_path = r"C:\Users\saviosebastian\MYD06_L2.A2008001.0000.006.2013341193524.hdf"   
    satellite = 'Aqua'

    yr = [2008]
    mn = [1]  #np.arange(1,13) 
    dy = [1] 

    # latitude and longtitude boundaries of level-3 grid
    lat_bnd = np.arange(-90,91,1)
    lon_bnd = np.arange(-180,180,1)
    nlat = 180
    nlon = 360

    TOT_pix      = np.zeros(nlat*nlon)
    CLD_pix      = np.zeros(nlat*nlon)

    ### To use Spark in Python
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("Aggregation")\
        .getOrCreate()
    filenames0=['']*500
    i=0
    for y,m,d in  itertools.product(yr,mn,dy):
        #-------------find the MODIS prodcts--------------#
        date = datetime.datetime(y,m,d)
        JD01, JD02 = gcal2jd(y,1,1)
        JD1, JD2 = gcal2jd(y,m,d)
        JD = np.int((JD2+JD1)-(JD01+JD02) + 1)
        granule_time = datetime.datetime(y,m,d,0,0)
        while granule_time <= datetime.datetime(y,m,d,23,55):  # 23,55
            print('granule time:',granule_time)
            **[MOD03_fp = 'MYD03.A{:04d}{:03d}.{:02d}{:02d}.006.?????????????.hdf'.format(y,JD,granule_time.hour,granule_time.minute)][1]**
            MOD06_fp = 'MYD06_L2.A{:04d}{:03d}.{:02d}{:02d}.006.?????????????.hdf'.format(y,JD,granule_time.hour,granule_time.minute)
            MOD03_fn, MOD06_fn =[],[]
            for MOD06_flist in  os.listdir(MOD06_path):
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(MOD06_flist, MOD06_fp):
                    MOD06_fn = MOD06_flist
            for MOD03_flist in  os.listdir(MOD03_path):
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(MOD03_flist, MOD03_fp):
                    MOD03_fn = MOD03_flist
            if MOD03_fn and MOD06_fn: # if both MOD06 and MOD03 products are in the directory
```

I am getting the following error:

[image: ERROR IMAGE.]

Do you know any solution to this problem?

Comment: You're calling [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) on a string that contains a path to a file. Should that really be a string that contains a directory name?

Comment: `C:\Users\saviosebastian\MYD06_L2.A2008001.0000.006.2013341193524.hdf` is invalid as per you error.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XtDVsPzT -- This is the code

Comment: So should I provide only the directory (in this case "C:/Users/saviosebastian/") instead of the entire path with filename in it? This is with regards to os.listdir()

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a specific answer without knowledge of the directory system on your computer, but for now it's obvious that there is something wrong with the name of the directory that you are referencing. Use File Explorer to make sure that the directory actually exists, and also make sure that you haven't misspelled the name of the file, which could easily happen given the filename.

Comment: You're making the same mistake as the OP: confusing file names with directory names. Files and directories are fundamentally different things. [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) operates on directories, not files.

Comment: I know, sorry for the lack of a distinction. The Directory error would then mean that something is wrong with the directory path and not with the filename. Thanks for the correction, although it wouldn't hurt to make sure that the name of the file is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the full path along with file name. The `os.listdir(path)` method in python is used to get the list of all files and directories in the specified directory. If we don’t specify any directory, then list of files and directories in the current working directory will be returned.

You can just write `"C:/Users/saviosebastian"` in path.
Same goes for `os.chdir("C:/Users/saviosebastian")`.